# How to Solve CORS on Spring Boot 3.0+

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors

Authentication does not work and all `POST` requests do not work in `Spring Security` in `Spring boot` versions `3.0.+`. It gives the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9090/api/rest/users/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

However, `GET` requests work and do not give this error. All recommendations working on the `Spring boot` version below `3.0`. type https://reflectoring.io/spring-cors/ do not work. I use the REST configuration with `JWT Token` implements `WebMvcConfigurer`.

I have tried connecting all the recommended headers both on the frontend side of the request and on the response side of the backend, but nothing helps. Apparently the problem is in the very sprig of these versions.Who has faced this problem and solved it, please respond.

```
 @Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Accept-Encoding, origin, content-type, accept, token, x-auth-token, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, " +
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, " +
                    "Content-Language, Content-Length, Keep-Alive, Authorization");



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Slf4j
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Bearer Authentication")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowedHeaders = "*")
//localhost:9090/api/rest/users
public class UserController extends GenericController<User, UserDTO>
{
    private final CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private final JWTTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService,
                          CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService,
                          JWTTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil) {
        super(userService);
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public ResponseEntity<?> auth(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        log.info("LoginDTO: {}", loginDTO);
        UserDetails foundUser = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(loginDTO.getLogin());
        log.info("foundUser, {}", foundUser);
        if (!userService.checkPassword(loginDTO.getPassword(), foundUser)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Ошибка авторизации!\nНеверный пароль");
        }
        String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(foundUser);
        response.put("token", token);
        response.put("username", foundUser.getUsername());
        response.put("authorities", foundUser.getAuthorities());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
}

@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
                .cors(withDefaults())
                ...
            return http.build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
    }

    import {useAuthUserAppStore} from "@/store/app";
import LoginDTO from "@/models/LoginDTO";

class AuthService {
  login(loginDTOUser: LoginDTO) {
    const user = {
      login: loginDTOUser.login,
      password: loginDTOUser.password
    }
    const serializedUser = JSON.stringify(user);
    return http
      .post('/users/auth', serializedUser)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.accessToken) {
          useAuthUserAppStore().changeAuthUser(JSON.stringify(response.data))
          console.log(useAuthUserAppStore().authUser)
        }

        return response.data;
      });
  }
```

Comment: why not just read the spring security documentation before asking here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html#page-title

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I also tried it didn't help

Comment: So you are claiming that the spring documentation is faulty?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, i read the documentation and still it is giving me cors error

Answer (score 0):

In the class `JWTSecurityConfig` I removed the bean:

```java
@Bean
public HttpFirewall httpFirewall() {       
    StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new 
    StrictHttpFirewall();       
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedPercent(true);
    firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
    firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
    firewall.setAllowedHttpMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
    return firewall;
}
```